# Create action works in practice, but controller tests won't pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Title pretty much explains the issue. I've literally pasted the submitted JSON POST data from a successful submission on the development serve into the test and it didn't work, so I'm confident the issue is in how I'm testing, not in the controller

Also, the testing suite is already pretty established for this app so I can't switch to RSpec.

Here's the failing message:

```
  1) Failure:
LessonsControllerTest#test_create [/test/controllers/lessons_controller_test.rb:24]:
"Lesson.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 1
  Actual: 0
```

Here's my test

```
def setup
  @user1    = users(:michael).id
  @user2    = users(:john).id
  @date1    = Date.parse('30-8-2015')
  @date2    = Date.parse('31-8-2015')
  @school1  = schools(:hhs).id
  @school2  = schools(:harper).id
end

test "create" do
  # Invalid submission
  assert_no_difference ['Goal.count', 'Lesson.count'] do
    post :create, lesson: { date: @date1,
                            school_id: @school1,
                            user_id: @user1,
                            goals_attributes: {'0' => { text: '',
                                                        user_id: @user1 }}}
  end
  # Valid submission
  assert_difference ['Goal.count', 'Lesson.count'], 1 do
    post :create, lesson: { date: @date1,
                            school_id: @school1,
                            user_id: @user1,
                            goals_attributes: {'0' => { text: 'test',
                                                        user_id: @user1 }}}
  end
```

And here's my controller, though I'm sure the error is elsewhere

```
def create
  find_or_initialize_lesson
  if @lesson.save
    flash[:success] = "Response logged"
    redirect_to @lesson
  else
    @user = current_user
    @school_options = School.all.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

  # strong params
  def lesson_params
    params.require(:lesson).permit(:school_id, :date,
                                   goals_attributes: [:id, :user_id,
                                                      :text, :lesson_id])
  end

  # Finds a lesson with the same date and school, or creates the lesson
  def find_or_initialize_lesson
    @lesson = Lesson.find_or_initialize_by(
      date: lesson_params[:date],
      school_id: lesson_params[:school_id]
    )
    goal = Goal.new(lesson_params[:goals_attributes]['0'])
    @lesson.goals << goal
  end
```

lesson.rb:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many   :users, through: :goals
  has_many   :goals, dependent: :destroy

  validates_presence_of :date, :school_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :goals
end
```

goal.rb

```
class Goal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :lesson
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :text
end
```

schools.yml

```
hhs:
  name: Hillsborough High School

harper:
  name: Harper High School
```

users.yml

```
michael:
  id: 1
  name: Michael Example
  email: test@example.com
  admin: false
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>

john:
  id: 3
  name: John Example
  email: john@example.com
  admin: false
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Comment: Your test could be failing a validation. Does Lesson.rb include any validations with unique constraint, for example?

Comment: Not failing a validation, I think, since I pasted the params from a successfully created Lesson via the development server and the test still failed. I'll update the post to include the models. And no, there's not a unique constraint

Comment: Just tested the validity and that test passed but the failing test still failed, so it's not a validity issue

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you post your users.yml and schools.yml fixtures? Just the bits that cover the named users and schools that you use.

Comment: Sure, added them now

Comment: Are you testing against a populated database (one where I could do User.find(1) and get the data for Michael Example *prior* to you running a test)?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm new-ish so I'm not familiar with this completely. I have fixtures defined, and I have seeds but not in my test database

Comment: Lessons depends on the schools and users to have been prepopulated, otherwise, you won't have IDs to feed to the create method, right? So if test.db is totally empty, create will fail. Are you manually creating lessons in test.db or dev.db?

Comment: I don't believe so, all I've got are fixtures. I assumed those were fine since I thought fixtures had IDs. How do you create entries in the test.db file?

Comment: I just added `puts School.find(@school1)` to my first test and it printed out `Hillsborough High School`. Not sure if that means it's been populated, but it does seem like it exists in this specific controller test

Comment: Sorry, dunno what I was thinking. Fixtures are db independent, so there goes that hypothesis.

Comment: It actually seems like the issue is fixed now. The problem was with the way that my sessions_helper interacted with my tests. Thanks for taking the time to help out